# Pyspark sql issue in regexp_replace regexp_replace(COALESCE("Today | is | good | day", ''), '\\|', '>')

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing issue with regex_replace funcation when its been used in pyspark sql. I need to replace a Pipe symbol `|` with `>`, for example :

```
regexp_replace(COALESCE("Today | is | good | day", ''),  '\\|',  '>')
```

input : `Today | is | good | day`
need the output : `Today > is > good > day`
But getting this : `>T>o>d>a>y> >|> >i>s> >|> >g>o>o>d> >|> >d>a>y>`

its happening only when a sql is been written in

```
job_ctx.spark.sql('''select regexp_replace(COALESCE("Today | is | good | day", ''),'\\|','>') as column''')
```

any one suggest how to solve this in pyspark.sql ?

Comment: Problem most likely is caused by backslashes: you `regexp_replace` interprets regex as `|`. Try to fiddle with it: delete one, add one or two, something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try with escaping with four slashes instead of two **`\\\\`**

```
spark.sql('''select regexp_replace(COALESCE("Today | is | good | day", ''),'\\\\|','>') as column''').show(10,False)
#+-----------------------+
#|column                 |
#+-----------------------+
#|Today > is > good > day|
#+-----------------------+
```

---

Other way would be using **`translate`** function so that we don't need to escape

```
spark.sql('''select translate(COALESCE("Today | is | good | day", ''),'|','>') as column''').show(10,False)
#+-----------------------+
#|column                 |
#+-----------------------+
#|Today > is > good > day|
#+-----------------------+
```